# Basic Counting -- Selecting groups of people from a group of 10

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I'm reading a series of basic counting problems regarding a ten person club. I just want to make sure I'm sufficiently grasping the material and my problem solving methods are correct.

> $1.$ In how many ways may a ten person club select a president and a secretary-treasurer from among its members?

For this problem, there are 10 ways to choose the president, and 9 ways to choose the secretary. In total, there are $10 \times 9 = 90$ ways to choose them.

> $2.$ In how many ways may a ten person club select a two person executive committee from among its members?

This time, since we're taking 2 people from 10, I used ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ ways.

> $3.$ In how many ways may a ten person club select a president and a two person executive advisory board from among its members (assuming that
>   the president is not on the advisory board)?

I've already established from my first answer that there are 10 ways to choose the president. Then, I have to choose 2 people from a remaining group of 9. ${9 \choose 2} = 36$. Finally, I multiply the two results.$36\times10 = 360$ ways.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It's correct :)

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: Ok, great, thank you guys!

Answer (score 1):

It is correct since you understand that the first answer requires a permutation since it is in a certain order, second requires combination because it is not chosen in any order, and the third is permutation and combination since one person is chosen in a specific order and the next two are chosen at random.

Answer (score 1):

All your answers are correct, and your reasoning is spot-on.

The only thing I'd like to point out is that for problem $1$, you can also use ${10 \choose 2} = 45$ to get the number of ways to pick the two people, and then there are two ways in which you can assign those two people to be president/secretary, and $45 \cdot 2 = 90$.